# C# HttpWebResponse doesn't return complete result?

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to use a php-webservice in my windows forms application, but I can't get the complete result.

I'm using the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestPath);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

If I'm calling the requestPath in my browser (or other restAPI tester) I'm getting the following example result:

```
VoteForm.className='inactive';Message='Vote inactive';
```

But in my code, 'result' contains just the first part:

```
VoteForm.className='inactive';
```

Is there a reason why it just stops at the ';' ?
What am I doing wrong?

edit: tried it with Fiddler, it's indeed returning just what I'm seeing in my program. Weird.

Here is the live example (trying to vote at a polldaddy.com poll, I know how to build up this url):
Request:

> http://polls.polldaddy.com/vote-js.php?p=9758311&b=2&a=44630094,&o=&va=0&cookie=0&n=90b22ea64f|775&url=http%3A//studiomike.be/Top%252040.html

Result via HttpWebRequest:

```
PD_button9758311.className='pds-vote-button';
```

Result in browser:

```
PD_button9758311.className='pds-vote-button';alert('Vote nonce has expired. Please try again.');
```

What could cause this difference?

Comment: First wrap all disposable objects (the response, the stream and the reader) into [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)s. Then verify (with e.g. [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) that you are indeed receiving `Message='Vote inactive';`.

Comment: is it possible to take a look at your request and response called from  browser

Comment: I tested with cURL and I see that the Content-Type of the response is "application/javascript". Maybe this confuses the HttpWebResponse and/or the StreamReader? You could read byte for byte instead, or try WebClient.DownloadString: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: On my computer, provided program returns complete response (including *alert(...)*)

Comment: `What could cause this difference?` - the user-agent? The cookies?